# How to use swagger for creating documentation using custom objects?

Tags: c#, swagger

I have a class that represent API, let's see:

```
[ApiEndpoint( Name, SignatureBase )]
[Title]
[Description]
abstract public class ReportsAPI
{
    public const string Name = "reports";

    public const string SignatureBase = "/system/report";

    static public readonly EndpointSignature Signature =
        SignatureBase;

    public class TitleAttribute
        : TitleLocalizedAttribute
    {
        public TitleAttribute()
            : base(typeof(Resources.ReportsAPITitle))
        {
        }
    }

    public class DescriptionAttribute
        : DescriptionLocalizedAttribute
    {
        public DescriptionAttribute()
            : base(typeof(Resources.ReportsAPIDescription))
        {
        }
    }

    [ApiCommands]
    abstract public class Commands
    {
        [ApiArgument(typeof(ReportTemplatesListArguments), isOptional: true)]
        [ApiReturn(typeof(ReportTemplatesListResponse))]
        [Title]
        [Description]
        public const string ReportTemplatesList = "report_templates_list";

        [ApiArgument(typeof(ReportTemplatesGetArguments))]
        [ApiReturn(typeof(ReportTemplatesGetResponse))]
        [Title]
        [Description]
        public const string ReportTemplatesGet = "report_templates_get";

        [ApiArgument(typeof(ReportsGenerateArguments))]
        [ApiReturn(typeof(ReportsGenerateResponse))]
        [Title]
        [Description]
        public const string ReportsGenerate = "reports_generate";
    }

    [ApiEvents]
    abstract public class Events
    {
        [ApiReturn(typeof(ReportGenerateStartedEvent))]
        [Title]
        [Description]
        [EventCategory(EventCategoryType.Audit)]
        [EventIsVerbalized]
        public const string ReportGenerateStarted = "report_generate_started";
    }
}
```

So this class tell us that we have commands, we can see their arguments and return values
and all I want is generate openapi documentation of this class for another people

I want smth like [this](https://editor.swagger.io/)
So my question is: Can swagger create documentation by this class for me?

Comment: Here is some documentation on that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments

Comment: but it is not for custom attributes